# 'npm i' error on Windows 8

Tags: node.js, windows-8, gruntjs, npm

I tried installing packages. On Windows 7 it's working perfectly, but on Windows 8 i got:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.14
3 info using node@v0.10.29
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
6 verbose install where, deps [ 'C:\\csssr-project',
6 verbose install   [ 'grunt',
6 verbose install     'grunt-autoprefixer',
6 verbose install     'grunt-bump',
6 verbose install     'grunt-combine-media-queries',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-clean',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-connect',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-copy',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-imagemin',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-jade',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-jshint',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-stylus',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-uglify',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-watch',
6 verbose install     'grunt-csscomb',
6 verbose install     'grunt-newer',
6 verbose install     'grunt-prettify',
6 verbose install     'grunt-replace',
6 verbose install     'grunt-spritesmith',
6 verbose install     'load-grunt-tasks' ] ]
7 info preinstall csssr-project-template@0.7.3
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 error Error: spawn ENOENT
9 error     at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
9 error     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:791:34)
10 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
10 error including the npm and node versions, at:
10 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
11 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
12 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
13 error cwd C:\csssr-project
14 error node -v v0.10.29
15 error npm -v 1.4.14
16 error syscall spawn
17 error code ENOENT
18 error errno ENOENT
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

my npm version:

> {
> http_parser: '1.0',
>     node: '1.10.29',
>     v8: '3.14.5.9',
>     ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
>     uv: '0.10.27',
>     zlib: '1.2.3',
>     modules: '11',
>     openssl: '1.0.1h',
>     npm: '1.4.23'
> }

my package.json

```
    {
    "name": "csssr-project-template",
    "version": "0.7.3",
    "title": "CSSSR Project Template",
    "description": "A template for a quick start.",
    "keywords": [
        "csssr",
        "project",
        "template",
        "frontend",
        "grunt",
        "jade",
        "stylus"
    ],
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/CSSSR/csssr-project-template.git"
    },
    "author": {
        "name": "GC92",
        "url": "https://github.com/GC92"
    },
    "copyright": "©CSSSR",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/CSSSR/csssr-project-template/issues/",
        "email": "production@csssr.com"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/CSSSR/csssr-project-template/",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.10.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.5",
        "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.8.2",
        "grunt-bump": "0.0.15",
        "grunt-combine-media-queries": "^1.0.19",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.8.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.7.2",
        "grunt-contrib-jade": "^0.11.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-stylus": "^0.17.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.5.1",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
        "grunt-csscomb": "^3.0.0",
        "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
        "grunt-prettify": "^0.3.5",
        "grunt-replace": "^0.7.8",
        "grunt-spritesmith": "^2.1.1",
        "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.6.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm cache clear"
    },
    "browsers": {
        "android": 4,
        "chrome": 35,
        "firefox": 30,
        "ie": 10,
        "ios": 6,
        "opera": 12,
        "safari": 6
    }
}
```

If I'm trying to delete scripts section from package.json, then installation begins, but not all dependecies are installed. In this case, grunt throws miscellaneous errors.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 : \`node-gyp rebuild\` Exit status 1 installing contextify as dependency of zombie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865562/windows-8-node-gyp-rebuild-exit-status-1-installing-contextify-as-dependency)

Comment: Do you still have a problem? Give another try to this scaffolder

Comment: @VladimirStarkov , nope.
My current NPM version:
    { npm: '2.5.1',
      http_parser: '2.
      modules: '14',
      node: '0.12.0',
      openssl: '1.0.1l
      uv: '1.0.2',
      v8: '3.28.73',
      zlib: '1.2.8' }
It's working.

Comment: Great =) [stupid-SO-have-restrictions-on-comment-length]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed in one of the updates.